# Is it possible to retrieve posts from LinkedIn's API?

Tags: linkedin-api

I would like to use LinkedIn's v2 API to monitor as many public-facing profiles as possible, and retrieve content from the posts made by those profiles. Then identify instances where LinkedIn users are linking to particular domains. I can't tell if this is possible through the Partner Program. Signs are pointing to using this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api but it isn't super clear to me whether this particular use case is supported.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. As long as they are authenticated member. I think this applied to Partner Program too. You need permission from owners to fetch their contents.

http:

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners={URN}&sharesPerOwner=100
```

The following authorization rules apply when specifying owners :

- For personal shares, you may only retrieve shares for the authorized members.

Source: [Find Shares by Owner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/share-api#find-shares-by-owner)

Comment: Hi, I am trying to retrieve the post as well from nodejs, and so far the 3 legged auth is not authorized for my application. I can only use the 2 legged auth which require to authenticate using a web form, which is not possible from node. Is there another way?